# How do I solve this using union-find algorithm?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, union-find

Question: http://codeforces.com/contest/468/problem/B

Little X has n distinct integers: p1, p2, ..., pn. He wants to divide all of them into two sets A and B. The following two conditions must be satisfied:

If number x belongs to set A, then number a - x must also belong to set A.
If number x belongs to set B, then number b - x must also belong to set B.
Help Little X divide the numbers into two sets or determine that it's impossible.

Input
The first line contains three space-separated integers n, a, b (1 ≤ n ≤ 105; 1 ≤ a, b ≤ 109). The next line contains n space-separated distinct integers p1, p2, ..., pn (1 ≤ pi ≤ 109).

Output
If there is a way to divide the numbers into two sets, then print "YES" in the first line. Then print n integers: b1, b2, ..., bn (bi equals either 0, or 1), describing the division. If bi equals to 0, then pi belongs to set A, otherwise it belongs to set B.

If it's impossible, print "NO" (without the quotes).

Now, I developed the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int n,a,b,id;
int p[100100];
set<int> st;
map<int,int> mp;

int fa[100100];

int find(int x)
{
    if(x==fa[x]) return x;
    return fa[x]=find(fa[x]);
}

void Bing(int a,int b)
{
    int A=find(a),B=find(b);
    if(A==B) return ;
    fa[B]=A;
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&a,&b);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",p+i);
        st.insert(p[i]);
        mp[p[i]]=++id;
        fa[i]=i;
    }
    fa[n+1]=n+1;///A
    fa[n+2]=n+2;///B

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int x=p[i];
        int flag = 0;
        if(st.count(a-x))
        {
            Bing(mp[x],mp[a-x]);
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Bing(n+1,mp[x]);
            flag = 1;
        }
        if(st.count(b-x) && flag == 0)
        {
            Bing(mp[x],mp[b-x]);
        }
        else if (flag == 0)
        {
            Bing(n+2,mp[x]);
        }
    }

    if(find(n+1)==find(n+2))
    {
        puts("NO");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("YES");
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            printf("%d ",find(i)==find(n+1));
        }
        putchar(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, try to merge every element with either in Set A or in Set B. And then finally output NO if both of them are merged in turn. However, this gives a wrong answer on input as:

```
3 3 4
1 2 4
```

Output should be: `NO` whereas my code gives output as

```
YES
0 0 1
```

Where am I going wrong in my logic? Please help!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem, but it looks like it gives the correct answer. If `1` and `2` both belong to `A`, then `3-1=2` and `3-2=1` both belong as well, and `4` and `4-4=0` both can belong to set B. Or does the result of subtraction also need to fit in the bounds?

Comment: Result of subtraction also needs to fit in the bound, yes.

Comment: I say this code is perfectly valid because the rules only specify the input must fit that range. However, it would help if your code had comments, or was explained in some way. I can't tell if you specifically check for that condition or not, but it would be my guess that the program considers `0` a valid result.

Comment: So let me share my understanding with other commentors: There is nothing like a number range for A and B. So given a = 3 and p1 = 2, the question is not whether 3-2=1 fits into the range, but whether p_i=1 actually exists in the input numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following cases for `P` being the set of all input numbers `p[i]`:

1. There is a number `n1 in P` that satisfies `n1 = a - p[i]` but no number `n2 in P` that satisfies `n2 = b - p[i]`
2. There is a number `n1 in P` that satisfies `n1 = b - p[i]` but no number `n2 in P` that satisfies `n2 = a - p[i]`
3. There is no number `n in P` that satisfies `n = a - p[i]` OR `n = b - p[i]`
4. There is a number `n1 in P` that satisfies `n1 = a - p[i]` AND a number `n2 in P` that satisfies `n2 = b - p[i]`

Whatever else may happen, if you run into situation 3. or 4. you want to report a failure ("NO").

If all numbers `p[i]` belong to case 1. or 2. the result should be valid.

You should check your code line by line, if it is compatible with the provided cases here.